# Unable to retrieve XMLTYPE through procedure

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

[image]I am trying to create a stored procedure to retrieve XMLTYPE as output. The problem is, query result is returning an error: unsupported data type.

I tried executing an existing procedure for similar XML Type but that as well is giving an error.

## Table:

`CREATE TABLE TBL_MYDATA
(
ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
MYDATA XMLTYPE
)`

## Procedure:

`CREATE PROCEDURE MYDATA
  (P_MYRESULT OUT XMLTYPE )
AS
BEGIN
SELECT MYDATA INTO P_MYRESULT FROM TBL_MYDATA WHERE ID = 1;
END MYDATA ;`

What could be going wrong suddenly?
Output screenshot:

Comment: What db client is the error in - you tagged with sqldeveloper and toad.

Comment: The error screenshot is in TOAD but I was not able to get result for this procedure in SQL Developer either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put some data into table?

I insert this record:

```
insert into TBL_MYDATA(id, mydata) values (1, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><text><para>hello world</para></text>');
```

And after that anonimous block successful complited:

```
begin
  P_MYRESULT  XMLTYPE;
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT MYDATA INTO P_MYRESULT FROM TBL_MYDATA WHERE ID = 1;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, the table has values that I can view when I double click on XMLTYPE column.Do you think there could be some database level settings impacting this ?